# SQL date conversion results to "ORA-01481: invalid number format model" after TO_DATE is changed to TO_CHAR

Tags: oracle11g

I am getting error while trying to run this query (shown below) :

```
SELECT 
TO_DATE (TERMIN_DATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AS TERMIN_DATE
FROM DRG_HDA_VOICE_VW T,DRG_CELL;
```

Initially it was giving error-

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P069 
ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
```

so I have used TO_CHAR in place of TO_DATE but now it's showing this error

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P069
ORA-01481: invalid number format model".
```

The data_type of "TERMIN_DATE" is VARCHAR2(14 Byte).

[image: DATA_TYPE(TERMIN_DATE)_image]

Any solution for this query?

Comment: Why, oh why are you storing a date as a VARCHAR? If you stored this as a proper `DATE` you wouldn't have this problems. If you can't convert the varchar to a DATE using `to_date()` it simply means you have stored invalid dates in that column (invalid meaning: the format of the value in the column does not match the format mask of your `to_char()` call)

Comment: @Ben the latter part of your original comment still stands, though - seems like the OP's data is shorter than the 14 characters specified in the datetime format mask.

Comment: One quick thing to try: `select termin_date from drg_cell where length(termin_date) < 14` (assuming the date is in `drg_cell` - otherwise use whichever table it's in). This will tell you if there are strings less than 14 characters in that column - regardless of what they are supposed to represent (such as dates). Please run this and report back, we'll see if we can help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your suggestions.                                                                                        @mathguy- I have tried that query and results are as follows:

```html
select termin_date from  DRGUSER01.DRG_HDA_VOICE_16281 where length(termin_date) < 14
TERMIN_DATE
+0800
+1000
+1200
+0500...

select termin_date from  DRGUSER01.DRG_HDA_VOICE_16281 where length(termin_date) > 14
empty

select termin_date from  DRGUSER01.DRG_HDA_VOICE_16281 where length(termin_date) = 14
TERMIN_DATE
20161128020303
20161128020304
20161128020010....
```

I think problem lies in input data format itself as you all had suspected.
I'll confirm back after testing the query with the corrected input data.